# subtree with networkX

Tags: python, tree, networkx, subtree

In networkX, I have a tree as DiGraph().

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import networkx as nx
t = nx.DiGraph()
t.add_edge(1,'r')
t.add_edge(2,'r')
t.add_edge(3,'r')
t.add_edge(4,2)
t.add_edge(5,2)
t.add_edge(6,5)
print t.edges()
```

If a take the node 2 of tree.
how I can get the subtree of 2 ?

#### Edit

I expected this subtree

```
[(4,2),(5,2),(6,5)]
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "subtree of 2" in your oriented/directed tree?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you mean the subtree rooted at node `2`, that's

```
from networkx.algorithms.traversal.depth_first_search import dfs_tree

subtree_at_2 = dfs_tree(t, 2)
```

**Edit**: it seems you've reversed the order of nodes in your edges. In a directed tree, all paths proceed from the root to a leaf, not the other way around. `dfs_tree(t.reverse(), 2)` gives you the tree that you want, but do change your code.

Comment: with this I get [(2, 'r')] and not is a subtree

Comment: @JuanPablo: that certainly *is* the subtree rooted at 2 in your graph. You've reversed the edges.

Comment: and in a undirected tree, how I can use dfs_tree ?

Comment: @JuanPablo: in an undirected tree, the notion of a unique subtree rooted at a node simply disappears; no can do. (There are still subtrees, but not unique ones per node.) You can still apply `dfs_tree`, but it will give you a directed tree containing all nodes, rooted at the node you give as an argument. Try `nx.draw(dfs_tree(t.to_undirected(), 2))`, for example.